# Can JSP expression language be used for Portlet environment?

Tags: jsp, portlet, liferay, el

I know a few Portals and I've never seen any usage of jsp expression language in any of them. Does it have a reason ? Because it seems, that there are no reasons for it.

I mean I tried to use it and it works. But for instance in Liferay portal, there are JSP expressions and scriptlets used only and it makes the code really unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

True, the bulk of the current Liferay display is heavy in scriptlets and display logic, but my opinion is that they are moving away from this.

My answer to your actual question is yes it is possible, but often not advised for the same reason you give. In addition there are many web frameworks that manage presentation much better than pure script/JSTL/EL which are also complatible with portlet development. eg [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home), [SpringMVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/portlet.html), JSF and Liferay MVCPortlet (to a lesser degree)

Comment: @David O'Meara: I'm afraid that Liferay doesn't seem to be moving away from this. The portal portlets and plugins they have created for past year or two are mostly based on struts1 and jsp (scriptlets and expressions) + taglibs. I was happy when vaadin mail plugin appeared, but otherwise there are only sample plugins for other technologies afaik. They should slowly move to view technologies with brighter future (spring-mvc,gwt,vaadin) instead of going deeper into jsp and struts1

Comment: I'm disappointed that the community is so big on one side, but so closed on the other side. It's usually big companies that invest a lot of financial resources into development, but they don't provide much back. They keep everything locked.

Comment: @lisak I guess I wishfully took the vaardin mail portlet as a sign that the internal portlets would improve, but upon reflection if you look at the way they are designed to be extended at the JSP layer including the various init.jsp files at each layer, it makes it a large job to completely rewrite and hence unlikely. I would wish that future Liferay work would also move away from this but again probably unlikely if it provides them so much benefit.

Comment: I've been trying to get permission to take parts of our internal work and add it to the blogsphere (ie my own blog at radio.coderanch.com) but it isn't always easy even if everyone is in agreement.

Comment: I can't access radio.coderanch.com, I guess that Liferay would have to come up with some sort of program that would be aimed for motivating companies to do this. On the other hand a lot of developers don't create new portlets, but integrate their existing apps into it (as Alfresco share is when deployed on server with Liferay)

Comment: d'oh radio.javaranch.com, you'd think I knew the address of my own blog but I've been quiet for a while. Liferay offers plenty out of the box and that may the problem: all other portlet development is client specific.

Comment: There's pro and con for staying with old libraries. At least Liferay's implementation is consistent - if you understand one of the core portlet's architecture, you understand all of them. However, there's quite some change: Version 6 introduced AlloyUI, together with enhanced taglibs for jsp, so that jsp was greatly simplified and the resulting HTML became more feature-rich just by using this library. /When/ something new is introduced (see AlloyUI), it's introduced throughout the /whole/ portal. You can't tell when some portlet has been written by identifying the library used. Hope that helps